# Toolchain from `executable` property does not match toolchain from `javaLauncher` property

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Community Edition)
JDK 1.8

Here my App.java

```
public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Interesting cases!" +
                "\nJDK: " + System.getProperty("java.version");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Here build.gradle:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 * This project uses @Incubating APIs which are subject to change.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
}

testing {
    suites {
        // Configure the built-in test suite
        test {
            // Use JUnit Jupiter test framework
            useJUnitJupiter('5.9.1')
        }
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'myproject.javatestdocker.App'
}
```

From terminal I success run app:

```
./gradlew run
```

Nice.

But when I try run app from IntelliJ IDEA (via green triangle) I get error:

```
> Task :app:App.main() FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:App.main()'.
> Toolchain from `executable` property does not match toolchain from `javaLauncher` property

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Does it help if you use Gradle 8.0.2 or 7.6.1 for this project, and reload the Gradle in the IDEA?

Comment: @LJreplica I use Gradle 8.0.1 in my project. Reload but it not help

Comment: There's a way that worked for me, but I didn't like it. You can open "Run configurations" and then select "Embedded JDK" in the jdk field, but I'm looking for a way to use my JAVA_HOME rather.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, running Java 11, with Gradle 8.0.2

The only solution, in my case, was to downgrade to Gradle 7.6.1, as follows:-

```
sdk uninstall gradle 8.0.2
sdk install gradle 7.6.1
```

Inside my project, I had to re-wrap so that 7.6.1 is the active Gradle for all.

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.6.1 --distribution-type all
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I've found a better workaround for it, not sure how well it works with task configuration avoidance/configuration cache, but I did not notice anything broken in my builds. Seems like IntelliJ/Android Studio generate a Gradle task for the run configuration on the fly, so you'd have to wait until the task execution graph is ready.

You can add this code snippet into your root project's `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    val task = this.allTasks.find { it.name.endsWith(".main()") } as? JavaExec // or whatever other method your Main class runs
    task?.let {
        it.setExecutable(it.javaLauncher.get().executablePath.asFile.absolutePath)
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to tweak the code a little to work for build.gradle. I added this in the subprojects config of the root project:         
        
```groovy        

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
        tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
            if (name.endsWith(".main()")) {
                println("Setting executable to java launcher for ${name}")
                it.setExecutable(javaLauncher.get().executablePath.asFile.absolutePath)
            }
        }
    } 
        
```

Answer (score 2):

most probably this is issue on intellij idea

to overcome this simply go to the gradle tab on the right side of the IDE then expand the tasks then expand applications then double click run from there

by the one you need to do that only once then the IDE run button will run using the last gradle run task you just used

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316081/Gradle-8-toolchain-error-Toolchain-from-executable-property-does-not-match-toolchain-from-javaLauncher-property-when-different

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Gradle 8.x, you can make it work by first creating your project by typing `gradle init` on the command line (instead of creating the project in IntelliJ IDEA). Then, once the project is created using `gradle init`, you can successfully open it in IDEA, wait for it to index everything, and you can then successfully run it.